# How to prompt user for filter criteria when importing data from MS SQL Server into MS Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, export-to-excel

I am trying to use Excel as a report mechanism for a SQL Server database. I created a view in SQL Server which pulls data from several tables and contains the columns needed in the report.

I created an Excel spreadsheet that connects to the view and imports the data needed. That part works great.

The final part I need to do is filter the dataset imported. The SQL Server table contains a column, `PickupDate` and I need to filter the dataset by prompting for a begin and end date so only the records with the `PickupDate` in the entered range is imported into the spreadsheet.

I don't know how to do this or even if it's possible. I did try to research this on my own but you are my last hope. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a connection in Excel that connects to your Data Source and DB, and you are able to get the results you want in the Excel file, then you could create a variable in your VBA to represent the user entry either via a Userform or a cell in your worksheet.

e.g.

**Userform**

*On clicking submit*

```
Dim param as String
param = Userform1.Textbox1.value
```

*your connection and query code here*

```
QUERY = QUERY + " WHERE PickupDate = " + param
```

**Cell in Excel**

```
Dim param as String
param = Range(your cell here).value
```

*your connection and query code here*

```
QUERY = QUERY + " WHERE PickupDate = " + param
```

Comment: I don't understand.  I've never used VBA.  There are thousands of records in the table that go back years but I only want to import the records for a 2 week pay period.  This is for a payroll clerk that knows nothing about databases or SQL etc.

Comment: BTW.  The spreadsheet is a pivot table that summarizes miles driven by driver name.

Comment: You should be able to see "PickupDate" as one of the fields in the PivotTable.  Just click and drag that to the "Filters" window.  From there you can filter on whatever dates you need